# Using continue in a do-while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, do-while, continue

[MDN states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#continue_Statement)

> When you use `continue` without a label, it terminates the current iteration of the innermost enclosing `while`, `do-while` or `for` statement and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.

I'm not sure why the following piece of code does not work as I expect.

```
do {
  continue;
} while(false);
```

Even though the `while` condition is `false`, I expect it to run forever since `continue` jumps towards the start of the block, which immediately executes `continue` again, etc. Somehow however, the loop terminates after one iteration. It looks like `continue` is ignored.

How does `continue` in a `do-while` loop work?

Comment: The condition being met is implied. If the condition isn't met, there's no next iteration.

Comment: I missed that. I guess I was misled by the order of the source code. (I thought `continue` would always "jump up" in the source code.)

Comment: It *does* seem that way, especially if you use a statement label. `TOP: do { continue TOP; } while(false)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YdpJ2/3/

```
var getFalse = function() {
  alert("Called getFalse!");
  return false;
};

do {
  continue;
  alert("Past the continue? That's impossible.");
} while( getFalse() );​
```

It appears to hit the continue, then break out of that iteration to run the check condition.  Since the condition is false, it terminates.

Answer (score 12):

`continue` does not skip the check `while(false)` but simply ignores the rest of the code within the brackets.

Answer (score 5):

Continue stops execution of the rest of the code in the block and jumps directly to the next iteration of your loop.

Since you are doing `while(false)` there is no next iteration

Answer (score 5):

`continue` doesn't start over the current iteration again but skips to the next one (as said in the MDN-quote).

because of  a `false` condition, there is no next iteration - so the whole loop is completed.

Answer (score 4):

> I expect it to run forever since continue jumps towards the start of
>   the block

The `continue` doesn't jump to the start of the block, it jumps to the end of the block.

Answer (score 3):

After the continue, the loop conditional is evaluated, since it is false, the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `while(true)` to get an infinite loop.

If you replaced `while(false)` with `while(true)`, you would get an infinite loop.

```js
do {
  continue;
} while(true);
```

`continue` skips to the end of the block, which in a do-while loop, will execute the conditional statement.

In your case, your condition was false and therefore it terminates the loop. If that condition is `true`, it would continue at the start of the loop.